# How do I check if a value is changed a certain amount within a second?

Tags: ios

I'm monitoring the Pitch and Roll Values in my application and i want to monitor to see if they change by 5 degrees within a second and then run a process. Currently my code looks like this:

```
 CMAttitude *attitude;
CMDeviceMotion *motion = scoringManage.deviceMotion;
attitude = motion.attitude;
basePitch = degrees(attitude.pitch);
baseRoll = degrees(attitude.roll);

if((pitchfloat >= basePitch+5) || (pitchfloat <= basePitch-5)) {


}
if((rollfloat >= baseRoll+5) || (rollfloat <= baseRoll-5)) {

}
```

That is called by:

```
yprTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(yprscore) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This process runs every second along with my timer but when the value is changed it will run that loop many times.

The Problem is that the if statements run like 20 times too many within that second.

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: sorry i meant the if statements

Comment: Where is this code? Is it called by a timer?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry again for my lack of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want it to run once the value is changed you need to set up a BOOL. Within your if pitch > 5 statement setup another if that checks that BOOL

```
if((pitchfloat >= basePitch+5) || (pitchfloat <= basePitch-5)) {
 if (firstTimeBOOLCheckisTrue == NO) {

 firstTimeBOOLCheckisTrue = YES;

 [self doSomething];
    }
}


(void *)doSomething{

if (imReadytoCheckPitchAgain == YES){
firstTimeBOOLCheckisTrue = NO;

}
```